# A way to manually upload new extensions into TFS 2017 U1?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I cannot find a way to upload the extension .zip archive to the TFS 2017 server "Manage Extensions" page, rather than installing via .vsix.

Our "legacy controls" only build the zip format "installer", and no "Upload new extension" button appears on the Extensions Management Page to allow them to be installed as-is, like in previous TFS versions (despite membership in TF-Administrators group with [Edit instance-level information] permissions for the TF Server).

I'm hoping not to have to build out .vsix packages for all of them (ya, because I'm lazy).

Any thoughts or experience to share?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, posting for any others looking for it.

To upload a Legacy control or extension in TFS 2017, from the Project Dashboard page, click the Settings button --> Server Settings.

Then, from the "Administer your server" page, click Legacy Extensions tab, 
  and then the Install button. When the 'Install new extension dialog appears, Browse and select the extension project zip file - Done.

Note: You can also disable any legacy extensions that may be incompatible from the Legacy Extensions Tab.

Hope that helps someone!

[Settings-Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noWC8.png)